# Flashcards: only forward or forward and reverse?

Tags: vocabulary, memorization

I've been trying do acquire more vocabulary. To do so, I've been reading everyday on my cellphone, highlighting new words and sharing them into a flashcard app.

The app allows me to create one-way or two-way cards. I've noticed that it's easier to know the meaning of the word when it's displayed in English first. When the word is shown in my native language, sometimes I can't remember that word in English.

So is it correct to study both sides of the cards?

Comment: I am not sure that this is an ELL question, but as a retired teacher the  simple answer is, yes, of course.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about  English , it is about how to teach or learn a skill.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was on topic since it's about learning new words, however, through flashcards.The only thing I was sure about is that the question was not on topic in https://english.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hey, one vote (mine) doesn't make it 'soup'. Best of luck with your studies.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same phenomenon happen to me when I am trying to learn new vocabulary for a foreign language (in my case, Spanish). I believe it is because you already know your language in and out. When you see an English word, you just have to remember what that word is in your massive vocabulary. However, you are trying to develop your English vocabulary, and you don't use it everyday. So, it is much harder to delve into your English vocabulary and find a word. I would definitely recommend going both ways, and even focusing on what is more difficult. As your vocabulary expands, so will your ability to translate both ways.

PS: This might want a migration to [LL.SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I agree that Language Learners would have been a better place to ask this question.